# Closing a FileOutputStream in java without a reference to it?

Tags: java

In java, we can do the following:

```
new FileOutputStream(new File("dir"));
```

(Excluding the exception handling for talks sake).

Should we somehow close the stream in this instance? if so how do we do it?  if we don't create a local reference within a method for example:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("dir"));
```

Is it bad practice to handle a stream shown in the first example? does java handle / close itself in that instance?

I receive some poor static code analysis when using the

```
foo = new FileOutputStream(new File("dir"));
```

because the stream is not closed, but I can't get a handle to close it? or maybe I can and i'm just not aware how.

Thank you all for the feedback, my apologies on not making my example relevant and clear.  please see my actual code below:

```
public void generateEnvironmentProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        properties.getAllProperties().forEach((k,v) -> props.setProperty(k,v));
        try {
            File f = new File("target\\allure-results\\environment.properties");
            if (!f.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create file(s)");
            }
            if (!f.createNewFile()) {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create file(s)");
            }
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(f), "Allure Environment Properties");
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            LOG.fatal(ioe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't create a variable for it, the stream is pointless as you can't do anything with it.

Comment: Technically, you can close it like this: `new FileOutputStream(new File("dir")).close()`

Comment: And yes you **should** close it or it leaks a file handle.

Comment: hmm  ```props.store(new FileOutputStream(f), "Allure Environment Properties");``` that seems to work just fine? I get a warning about now closing this FileOutputStream

Comment: You call `new FileOutputStream(new File("dir")).close();`. Otherwise you should declare a variable and use it in several lines of code (I know, legacy didn't really do one-liners).

Comment: @Jackofspace What is `props`? Can you show a complete example?

Comment: ah yes! ok thank you all, well that was easy.  Thanks again

Comment: @Jackofspace from your comment, then you're only creating it because it is part of properties of another object that should handle closing it.

Comment: You need to provide more context, because as it stands it looks like you're just trying to be obtuse with your question instead of defining a real problem that can be solved.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov What is the purpose of `new FileOutputStream(new File("dir")).close();`? This appears to be a no op.

Comment: Java has mechanisms which can clean up things like open files, but in general it's a really bad idea to rely on these mechanisms, because you are not guaranteed that they will work.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Which mechanisms are you referring to?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, it's not, actually. It will check that the file exists, that your code has permissions to write in it, and it will actually create and initialize a file descriptor that's ready to write in file. And then all that will be closed right after.

Comment: thank you all, my apologies I updated with my actual code

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, `finalize()` does close the file stream. As I said, it's silly to rely on it really doing that though.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov So you are talking about the garbage collector calling it? Then yes, you should not rely on that because you cannot rely on the timing. On the other hand, try-with-resources is guaranteed to close the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
props.store(new FileOutputStream(f), "Allure Environment Properties");
```

DON'T DO THIS. As your IDE warns you, the output stream will not be closed. You have two options:

1. Keep a reference to the stream and close it yourself. You will need to write the correct `try...catch...finally` statement to make sure the stream is closed even if an exception is thrown.
2. If you are using Java 7 or later, use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). This new form of the try...catch statement will automatically close a stream when the try block exists.

Answer (score 3):

As the [Properties.store](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)) javadoc says:

> After the entries have been written, the output stream is flushed.
>     The output stream remains open after this method returns.

So it is indeed required that you hold on to the instance of `FileOutputStream` you're using and close it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

you can use try-with-resources, one of the Java 7 feature

```
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)){
    // use resources, for example:
    props.store(fos , "Allure Environment Properties");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // exception handling, for example:
    LOG.fatal(ioe);
}
```

the resources are closed as soon as the try-catch block is executed

Comment: Based on the code provided by OP, this will close the resource before being used. Thus, is not a proper solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, no, not really. He just needs to call `properties.store()` inside the `try` block.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this to include the equivalent of the code in the question.